# Matchsticks Problem : Finding Maximum Squares Formed by $n$ Sticks

Tags: problem-solving, pattern-matching

Given $n$ sticks, what is the formula for how many squares that can form with the sticks, where the square's sides each one matchstick?  No breaking the matchsticks or allowing them to intersect.  Also, the matchsticks are only to be placed on a 2-d plane.

So, the sequences will be :

$\{4, 7, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 27, 29, 31, 34, 36, 38, 40, ... \}$

**Explanation :**

For $n = 4$ sticks, only 1 square can be formed

[n = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRQSo.png)

For $n = 7$ sticks, we can form 2 squares

[n = 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiQoi.png)

For $n = 10$ sticks, there are 3 squares

[n = 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw0aj.png)

For $n = 12$ sticks, we can form 4 squares

[n = 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22kKD.png)

**Note :**
I have been searched for this question on the internet, the formula will be

For $n\geq 4$ , where $r\geq 1, c\geq 1, 0 \leq a < r$ and $r, c, a \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then the formula was

$r + c(2r + 1) + 2a + \left \lceil \frac{a}{a+1} \right \rceil \leq n$

I found it in this [link](https://www.quora.com/You-are-given-n-matches-your-task-is-to-arrange-the-matches-not-necessarily-all-such-that-number-of-rectangle-any-size-is-maximum-Any-formula-or-pattern)

But it can't help me for finding the simple and easy formula from n variable. Because I just found the formula by the n variable without any other variable to make this problem solved quickly

Comment: You are missing several figures.  Please fix the question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot about it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: In the formula you give, you toss around an alphabet of letters ($a,c,r$) without telling us what any of them mean. Better to give us the link to where you found the formula, maybe someone will be able to understand it, and to help you.

Comment: Okay, I've been updated the question. Thank's for the suggestion

Comment: The numbers are tabulated, with formulas and links, at http://oeis.org/A078633 – why not have a look there, and report back on your findings?

Comment: That link you gave is counting the number of rectangles, not the number of $1\times1$ squares, and you have left out the formula it gives for $f(n)$, the formula that gives $f(n)$ as the maximum over a range of values of $a,c,r$ of a sum involving a product of binomial coefficients. Do you really want all rectangles, or just all $1\times1$ squares?

Comment: From the link that I've given, the question wants all rectangles, but the answers were only $1\times 1$ squares.
I want the solution for just all $1\times 1$ squares.

Comment: Yes, the link that you gave was correct. Thanks for sending the link and give me the solution @GerryMyerson . I will report back to my findings

Comment: Please post your answer to this question @GerryMyerson.
Thank you very much for sending the solution.

Comment: What I had in mind was that you report back *here*, by posting an answer based on what you have found by following the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that OP wants a formula for the sequence $$4,7,10,12,15,17,20,22,24,27,29,31,34,36,38,40,\dots$$ This sequence gives the smallest number of sticks of length $1$ needed to construct $n$ squares with sides of length $1$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and is tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A078633). The formula given there is $$a_n=2n+\lceil2\sqrt n\rceil$$ where $\lceil m\rceil$ is the *ceiling function*, the smallest integer not less than $m$. A proof is given in Buchholz and de Launey, [The square, the triangle, and the hexagon](https://ca827bd0-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/teufelpi/papers/sth.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7coMrxJc9CBMvU_VFaULxwHDt1Wd5He0W71FFBigyNmc5rlhpdp0Q0LDOTOz_r7yuvK35aBVfwwLgncBNRR25OB5tHAjfGpVUGiCiO70mOEVHvy_d6IqPsAoRahjOVb5vs393j1AlX3DABypTNDPZFGmQAubJyefp1IWZYLNJDG8JQxhUXL58p99DMa8kwn0xdI-3mdMaRx2bXJZ7Dr4uvI9ZwdmVQ%3D%3D&attredirects=0). This link is also taken from the OEIS.